# How to save textfield response without clearing

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying to create a simple to do list style app. I have successfully saved the string using SharedPreferences, as I am able to refer to it in the Logs, but I would like to make it so that the string stays attached to the textfield instead of being cleared every time app is reopened (until changed or deleted by the user). Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

(MainActivity)

```
public void go(View view) {

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, myPreferences.class);

    String passGoal1 = goal1.getText().toString();

    intent1.putExtra("goal1", passGoal1);

    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Also implemented myPreferences class as referenced in the first answer.

```
public class myPreferences {

    private SharedPreferences pref;

    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private Context context;

    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    private static final String PREF_NAME = "MyPreferencesName";

    public final static String KEY_NAME = "key_value";

    public myPreferences(Context context) {

        this.context = context;

        pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,PRIVATE_MODE);

        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setFunction(String data) {

        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shared preferences make a get function that fetch the stored data and view it every time in textfield

```
public class MyPreferences {

private SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor for Shared preferences
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

// Context
private Context context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "MyPreferencesName";

public final static String KEY_NAME = "key_value";

public MyPreferences(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void setFunction(String data) {
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME, data);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getFunction() {
    return pref.getString(KEY_NAME, "");
}
}
```

And in your activity initialize SharedPreferences and do the following:

```
private MyPreferences myPreferences;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myPreferences = new MyPreferences(this);

    //To set EditText data from SavedPreferences
    textField.setText(myPreferences.getFunction());
}

//To save the latest data from EditText.
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.d("LifeCycle", "onStop: ");
    super.onStop();
    myPreferences.setFunction(editText.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am getting a error when trying to set up the AppSettingsPreference class, any suggestions?

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you, i've edited my answer, try again and hopes everything is going ok now. @Ian F.

Comment: Thank you so much. One last question sorry, how could I pass the data from the textfield to this new class though? Would I just pass it back and forth using a new intent?

Comment: Check my answer update, hope everything is going to be ok and clear now, if you need anything more just leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you :) really appreciate your patience if only more people did.

Comment: it's my pleasure to help you and am ready for any other questions. ^_^

Comment: Sorry one last question, so do I need to create three separate key values for three separate text fields? As it stands now it sets all three text fields to the value of the third text field for some reason.